# How to use argparse with both python and program flags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

```
python -i prog.py -h
```

When calling the above command I get the expected output with a traceback and 'SystemExit: 0'. Without '-i' I get the expected output without a traceback. Why does this happen and is there a way to use both python flags and program flags in the same command without the traceback?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing your code. A basic example that I just tried works without issue. What platform are you running on? Windows? Linux?

Comment: @scotty3785 I am running on linux (ubuntu 15.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Python with the `-i` flag changes the handling of the `SystemExit` exception, which is used for things like `sys.exit`. Normally, an uncaught `SystemExit` causes Python to silently exit. However, with `-i` on, `SystemExit` is treated like any other exception, with a traceback and everything.

If you want to silence `SystemExit` tracebacks with `-i` on, you'll need to explicitly catch and ignore them. For example,

```
def main():
    try:
        ...
    except SystemExit:
        # Catch the exception to silence the traceback when running under python -i
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ah ok, so this has nothing to do with argparse and everything to do with exiting in interactive mode. Should I go ahead and delete this question to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Jay: It seems like the question could be useful to future readers. I'd leave it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit):

```
exception SystemExit
This exception is raised by the sys.exit() function. When it is not handled, the Python interpreter exits; no stack traceback is printed.
```

argparse employs the SystemExit exception with the '-h' option, and since you enter interactive mode with the command line argument '-i' you see the traceback.  Notice that the traceback is *not* printed if you implement and send in a different option:

```
python -i prog.py -p 80
```

Two immediate "quick-fixes" I can think of (but really, it comes down to what do you really need this for?)

1. Put in a try-except clause when parsing your arguments.
2. python -i prog.py -h 2> /dev/null